# Timed Events with Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, touch, scheduled-tasks

I'm looking for advice, and maybe a few examples. I'm trying to figure out how to create a `CCSprite` and have the player touch it as close to `int aCertainAmountOfTime` after it was created as possible. I want the player's score to be determined by how close to the 1 second mark they hit the item, with a lower score for being too early or too late.

Would this be best solved by creating some sort of schedule update, or a tick? I've never done that, and I'm a bit confused about the logic of it. I understand the need, but not how to implement it.

I know this question is vague, but I'm a little bit lost, and any advice would be appreciated. Can someone share a basic example of when a scheduled update tick would be relevant, and how the code would look?

Thanks for dealing with my ambiguity =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is quite simple, you only need to add this to your CCSprite class' init method:

```
[self scheduleUpdate];
```

Then update just counts the time since it was created (lifeTime is a float ivar declared in the class' @interface):

```
-(void) udpate:(ccTime)delta
{
   lifeTime += delta;
}
```

When the user touches the sprite, just subtract 1 from lifeTime to get the time difference relative to 1 second:

```
-(void) playerTouchedMe
{
   int diff = lifeTime - 1.0f;
}
```

If diff is negative, the player touched too early by this many seconds. If diff is positive, the player touched too late by this many seconds. And to get the absolute difference you'd use fabsf, ie basically it just removes the sign (if any):

```
int absoluteDiff = fabsf(diff);
```

Done.

Comment: This seems like a good approach. The delta part is important.

Comment: I think I like this answer the best. Can you maybe explain what adding `scheduleUpdate` to the CCSprite class actually does? I'm trying to extrapolate the information you gave me here, so I can use the concepts elsewhere. Thanks for your time!

Comment: scheduleUpdate simply instructs Cocos2D to call the -(void) update:(ccTime)delta method once per frame. This is generally used to advance your game each frame, for example changing the sprite's position etc.

Answer (score 1):

From what you explained, I think that scheduling an update to handle this would be overkill and kind of pointless.

You could create your object by composing CCSprite and a NSDate to hold the time it was placed on the scene (probably on -(void)onEnter ), add touch detection ( CCTouchDispatcher's addTargetedDelegate) and comparing the difference between the touch date and the creation date with your amount of time.

If you need code example let me know and I'll add it later. This is written from a phone.

Edit: Adding missing code

```
@interface TimedObject : CCNode <CCTargetedTouchDelegate> {
    CCSprite    *sprite_;
    NSDate      *spawnDate_;
    NSUInteger  amountOfTime_;
}

-(id)initWithSprite:(CCSprite *)sprite andTime:(NSUInteger)amountOfTime;

@end

@implementation TimedObject

-(id)initWithSprite:(CCSprite *)sprite {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        sprite_ = sprite;
        [sprite_ setPosition:ccp(sprite_.contentSize.width * 0.5, sprite_.contentSize.height * 0.5)];
        [self addChild:sprite_];

        [self setContentSize:sprite_.contentSize];

        amountOfTime_ = amountOfTime;
    }
}

-(void)onEnter {
    [super onEnter];

    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];

    spawnDate_ = [[NSDate date] retain];
}

-(void)onExit {
    [super onExit];

    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate:self];
    [spawnDate_ release];
    spawnDate_ = nil;
}

- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    touchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];

    CGRect touchArea;
    touchArea.origin = CGPointZero;
    touchArea.size = self.contentSize;

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(touchArea, touchLocation)) {
        // Tapped inside

        NSTimeInterval interval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:spawnDate_];

        // Check here and handle
        if (interval > amountOfTime) {
            // over
        }
        else {

        }

        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}

@end
```

Comment: Scheduling update is overkill, but this isn't? I think it's the other way around.

Comment: This only accesses the object when tapped. By scheduling the update you're changing the object's state 60 times per second. As far as it may be simpler to code, it feels to me that it is accessing and changing that float without need.

Comment: Maybe so, but it's a very, very cheap operation.

Answer (score 0):

i would do that by creating a subclass of sprite , say MySprite with a float counter inside as a private member instance.

then in your main loop say

```
-(void) nextFrame:(ccTime) dt {

[mysprite tick:dt]

if( mysprite.isExpired ) {
  //stuff here
}
```

in your touch method, when you thouch the sprite you can get

```
float score = mysprite.score;
```

implementing tick and properties isExpired and score is pretty straightforward

```
-(void) tick:(ccTime) dt {
  counter += dt; //increment the private counter
}
```

@property (readonly, nonatomic) BOOL isExpired;

```
-(BOOL) isExpired {
return counter > TIME_LIMIT ? YES : NO;
}
```

and @property (readonly, nonatomic) float score simply return your computer score based on time elapsed

Answer (score 0):

Create a `CCNode` subclass. We'll call it `Custom`. Within `Custom`, there will be a `CCSprite` instance (called `mySprite`) and a `float` property (called `myTimer`). So far we got something like this then:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface Custom : CCNode {
    CCSprite *mySprite;
    float myTimer;
}
@property(readwrite)float myTimer;
@end
```

Good. Remember to initialize `myTimer` in the `init` function of `Custom`. The value would be `0.0`.

Now go to your game scene. Here we will set a schedule. Go to the `init` function of your game scene and put:

```
[self schedule:@selector(updateCustomTimers:)interval:0.1];
```

Naturally, you will have to create a `updateCustomTimers` method in your game scene class. Good, now all you have to do is iterate through every `Custom` instance you have and increase their timers:

```
-(void)updateCustomTimers {
    for (Custom *myCustomInstance in arrayOfCustomInstances) {
        myCustomInstance.myTimer += 0.1;
    }
}
```

Note that `arrayOfCustomInstances` is an `NSMutableArray` which is supposed to hold all instances of `Custom` in your game scene. So whenever you create a new `Custom` instance, add it also to the array.

Now you have a way to update individual timers for every single sprite (wraped in a custom class) in your game. The scoring calculation should be easy from here (you can access the timer of any `Custom` instance you got by using the `myTimer` float property).